# Brownian Motion Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $(W(t))_{t\geq 0}$ be a Brownian motion and $0<s<t.$
What is the distribution of $2W(s)-W(t)$?

If $s>t$, then $2W(s)-W(t) \sim W(4s)-W(t) \sim N(0, 4s-t)$, but here we have $t>s$.

Does this calculations still hold?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $t>s$
$$\begin{aligned}E[e^{i\xi(-(W_t-2W_s))}|\mathscr{F}_s]&=E[e^{-i\xi(W_t-W_s)}|\mathscr{F}_s]e^{i\xi W_s}\\
&=e^{-(t-s)\xi^2/2}e^{i\xi W_s}\\
\implies E[e^{i\xi(-(W_t-2W_s))}]&=e^{-t\xi^2/2}
\end{aligned}$$
If $s>t$
$$\begin{aligned}E[e^{i\xi(2W_s-W_t)}|\mathscr{F}_t]&=E[e^{i\xi 2W_s}|\mathscr{F}_t]e^{-i\xi W_t}\\
&=E[e^{i\xi 2(W_s-W_t)}|\mathscr{F}_t]e^{i\xi W_t}\\
&=e^{-4(s-t)\xi^2/2}e^{i\xi W_t}\\
\implies E[e^{i\xi(2W_s-W_t)}]&=e^{-4(s-t)\xi^2/2}e^{-t\xi^2/2}\\
&=e^{-(4s-3t)\xi^2/2}
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Brownian motion can be realized as the (continuos realization) of a Gaussian process $W_t$ such that
$$
\mathbb{E}[W_t]=0
$$
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(W_t,W_s)= \min (s,t)
$$

The variance of the difference is
$$
\operatorname{Var}(2W(s)-W(t))= 4\mathbb{E}[W(s)^2]+\mathbb{E}[W(t)^2] -4\operatorname{Cov}(W(s),W(t))=4s+t-4 \min(s,t)
$$

So we have
$$
2W(s)-W(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,4s+t-4 \min(s,t))
$$
or, if you prefer
$$
2W(s)-W(t) \sim W(4s+t-4 \min(s,t))
$$

Notice how, if $t>s$ you have
$$
2W(s)-W_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)
$$

while if $t<s$ you have
$$
2W(s)-W(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,4s-3t)
$$

consistently with the other answers