# If $W_t$ is a Brownian motion $\operatorname{Cov}\left( c^{-\frac{1}{2}} W(cs), W(t) \right)\ne \operatorname{Cov}(W(s),W(t))$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $W(t)$ a Wiener process. By the scaling propety of the Brownian motion we have that
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}} W(ct)
$$
is a Wiener process. Let $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \ge 0}$ the Filtration of the Wiener process and suppose $cs <t$. Then $W(cs)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable

As $\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}} W(cs) \sim W(s)$ ($\sim$ here is equality in law) it looks to me that

$$
\operatorname{Cov}\left( c^{-\frac{1}{2}} W(cs), W(t) \right)=  \operatorname{Cov}(W(s),W(t))
$$
But looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4865128/brownian-motion-distribution/4865193#4865193) question (in particular one of the comments and the accepted answer) it looks like this is not the case.

Is this formula false? In that case what is $\operatorname{Cov}( c^{-\frac{1}{2}} W(cs), W(t) )$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt c} W(cs)$ is a Brownian motion, but it isn't the same Brownian motion that you started with, so $\text{Cov}(\frac{1}{\sqrt c} W(cs),W(t)) \ne \text{Cov}(W(s),W(t))$.  Instead, using standard rules of covariance and the fact that $cs < t$, we have
\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}(\frac{1}{\sqrt c} W(cs),W(t)) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt c} \text{Cov}(W(cs),W(t)) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt c} cs \\
&= \sqrt{c} s
\end{align*}

Comment: user6247850. That's an interesting answer. But, it made me think of the following question: If one constructed a plot where the non-scaled one started first and then  stopped and the other scaled one took over, would one be able to tell the difference between them ? In other words, how does one "know" that it's a different BM.

Comment: @markleeds So to be clear, do you mean plotting a trajectory of $W(t)$ on $[0,T]$, and then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}} W(ct)$ on $(T,\infty)$?  There would be a discontinuity at $T$, for one thing.  One knows that it's a different BM because $\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}} W(ct) \ne W(t)$ in general.  Sorry, I'm having a little bit of difficulty understanding exactly what you mean in this question.

Comment: user6247850. thanks for your response. I definitely wasn't clear. Let me phrase it differently. In descriptions of brownian motion in textbooks, it is always written that one of the requirements for something to be BW is that cov(w(s),w(t)) = min(s,t). When they write such a thing, are they assumng that w is the same brownian motion the whole time or could they be two different brownian motions ? Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds Yes, they are assuming it is the same BM the whole time for that covariance expression.  If they were allowed to be different, we could have two independent BMs $W$ and $\hat W$.  Then $\text{cov}(W(s),\hat W(t)) = 0$ for all $s,t$.

Comment: gotcha. that makes sense and also explains why the covariance result in your answer doesn't have to be min(s,t). your help and patience is appreciated.